# In what cases do I use Json or Hibernate?

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I have an application to access to postgreSQL database . 
 I'm confused to choose between Json format or Hibernate for my DAO layer , Actually I'm using Spring for my buisness layer.

Comment: Forget Spring. Use standard Java EE 6 technologies (JPA using EclipseLink or Hibernate, JSF 2, CDI, ...). :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON format and hibernate are two different things. JSON is a a data format in which your data is passed to and from UI and server side code. And hibernate is an ORM which we use to deal with database. Database operations are carried out by hibernate.
If your needs are such data returned by spring controller should be in JSON format, use JSON. And use hibernate for database operations. The objects returned by your DAO layer, will be converted to JSON and will be sent back to UI by spring controller in JSON format.